# Access All rows of Grid View

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I have a grid view with page size of 6. Now in a button click event I need to access all the available rows of grid view as all the control are editable so I need to scan all the element.
However the statement

```
For Each row As GridViewRow In UserNoteGrid.Rows
```

run only for the current page not for all the available rows in every page.
How can I access that.
Thanks

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this and this is the default behaviour. You can only access rows which are actually loaded in the grid not the ones which are in the backend datasource.

Comment: It Seems like its not possible so to do so you need to implement some logic in your code. Anyway Thanks

Answer (score 0):

please check ...

```
    'after binding
    GridView1.AllowPaging = False
    For Each row As GridViewRow In GridView1.Rows
        'some work
    Next
    GridView1.AllowPaging = True
```

Comment: please check this page : [How to access all rows in a gridview](http://forums.asp.net/t/1272593.aspx/1)

Answer (score 0):

you can use somethings like this:

```
Protected Sub UserNoteGrid_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles UserNoteGrid.RowDataBound
    e.Row.Cells(1).Text = "test ..."
End Sub
```

Comment: Actually requirement for accessing all the rows was in different method rather than in RowDataBound. I couldn't do this so I change in my logic and did the task. thanks for being active for this problem.